# How do Concentration checks interact with damage that is not lethal damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, concentration

Odd question came up in a game today and that was how is a concentration check affected by damage that is not lethal damage.

So these other sources are non-lethal damage, ability score damage, and ability score drain. I assume that non-lethal would be performed the same way as lethal. Its the ability score ones that I dont even know if they would affect the check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ability Score damage doesn't trigger a Concentration check. Nonlethal damage does.

Looking carefully at the relevant rules, it appears that ability damage doesn't actually damage the *character*, but rather damages their *[scores](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/BASICS-ABILITY-SCORES/ability-scores/#Ability_Score_Damage)*.

> Diseases, poisons, spells, and other abilities can all deal damage directly to your ability scores.

Since this damage is affecting a character's scores, and not the character themselves, the damage doesn't count under the Injury section of the [Concentration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Concentration) rules.

> If you take damage while trying to cast a spell, you must make a concentration check

[Nonlethal damage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Nonlethal-Damage), however, is still damage to a character.

> When you take nonlethal damage, keep a running total of how much you’ve accumulated.

Since Injury applies whenever a character takes damage, taking nonlethal damage still requires a Concentration check.

Comment: The lines immediately following your quote about Ability Score damage negate the quoted line... "For every 2 points of damage **you take** to a single ability, apply a –1 penalty to skills and statistics listed with the relevant ability. If the **amount of ability damage you have taken** equals or exceeds your ability score, you immediately fall unconscious..." I think that portion is just poorly stated

Comment: Does the portion of Nonlethal damage "Do not deduct the nonlethal damage number from your current hit points. It is not “real” damage." affect your answer?